# Windws 7 laptop may reboot while running Ubuntu Server 12.10 guest in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, bsod

On my Windows 7 machine, I am running VirtualBox 4.2.4 with Ubuntu Server 12.10 as a guest.

Sometimes, when I run the Ubuntu guest, my whole laptop reboots.

Has anyone experienced this, and how can I prevent this?  I expect if something is wrong with the VirtualBox guest, only the guest needs to reboot.  Why would the host machine need to reboot?

Comment: This is almost certainly a BSOD.  Hold F8 as your (host) computer starts and select **Disable automatic restart on system failure**.  Then try running VirtualBox again and post the error message you get, especially the codes that start with `0x`.  This will help us understand exactly what the problem is.